# How to update data as null in mysql using php loop?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a table named users with a column called user_subs. It looks like this.

[image: Users table showing users in user_subs]

In user_subs I have stored the specific users session username. Lets say this specific users name is James.

Now how would I loop through a specific user_subs looking for "James" and remove him from that specific user_subs without removing all the other names.

This is what I have so far and the only problem is, its deleting all the usernames in user_subs instead of just "James".

```
if(isset($_GET['p_id'])) {
  $the_post_id = $_GET['p_id'];
  $the_post_author = $_GET['author'];
}

if(isset($_POST['delete_sub'])) {
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];

  $query = "SELECT user_subs FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
  $select_users_by_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_users_by_id)) {
    $user_subs = explode(',', $row['user_subs']);

    foreach($user_subs as $out) {

      $query = "UPDATE users SET user_subs = null WHERE username = '{$the_post_author}' ";

       $unsubscribe_user = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

       echo "Unsubscribed";
    }
  }
}
```

THIS IS JUST IN TEST, PREPARED STATEMENTS WILL BE USED BEFORE GOING LIVE

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You want to overwrite the row or delete it?

Comment: Ideally, you'd probably have the user subs in another table and only delete the specific person. Otherwise, you've got to parse that data, remove the unwanted data and put the rest back.

Comment: @tereško Well if you use delete it will delete the whole column thats why you have to use update and null

Comment: Have you checked that this column can contains `NULL` value? It might be possible, that the table was create with `NOT NULL` constraint on the `user_subs` column.

Comment: @tereško Yes it can, its removing all the names in user_subs though.

Comment: Well ... you will have to debug it all then. Try doing some `var_dump()` calls to know, what is being passed to each query. And run some `SELECT` queries with the same conditions as that `UPDATE` query of yours. See what it spits out.

Comment: Your first query is completely unnecessary. In fact, it's counterproductive!

Comment: @Strawberry Why is it unnecessary? First it has to select everything in user_subs right?

Comment: @tereško var_dump on user_subs outputs this -- array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "BSmyth" [1]=> string(5) "James" [2]=> string(5) "Sally" }

So it seems to be looping correctly.

Comment: No. There's no 'first' about it.

Comment: @Strawberry When I pull out the query it breaks the code

Comment: At the core of this problem is a lack of normalization. Fix that, and the other problems will evaporate.

Answer (score 0):

I second the other user's comment about moving this column to a different table. In the meanwhile, if you want to achieve what you are asking for, you can try removing the user name from the column value and update it with the remaining text.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_sub'])) {
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];

  $query = "SELECT user_subs FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
  $select_users_by_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_users_by_id)) {
    $user_subs = str_replace($username . ',', '', $row['user_subs']);

$query = "UPDATE users SET user_subs = '{$user_subs}' WHERE username = '{$the_post_author}' ";

       $unsubscribe_user = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
       echo "Unsubscribed";

  }
}
```

**OPTION-2**

```
$user_subs = explode(',', $row['user_subs']);
$user_subs_new = [];
foreach($user_subs as $out) {
    if ($out !== $username) {
        $user_subs_new[] = $out;
    }
}
$user_subs = implode(',',user_subs_new);
  $query = "UPDATE users SET user_subs = '{$user_subs}' WHERE username = '{$username}' ";

   $unsubscribe_user = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

   echo "Unsubscribed";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its still removing all names

Comment: Can you print `$user_subs` before the query?

Comment: If I print $user_subs nothing prints but if I print $row it outputs "array"

Comment: See what is coming in `$row['user_subs']` and if `$username` matches with any values in there. I do not see username in your table structure, so not sure if it is exactly same as what is in the user_subs column. Your best bet is to try printing values of each of these variables at each and every step to understand what is missing. The idea behind my answer is to get the user_subs value for the given user from the DB and update that string using php to remove whatever you don't need and then use the update query to set the new user_subs string for that user .

Comment: Yea I see what you're trying to do, and I appreciate the different approach. 

For my code above if I var_dump $user_subs after the explode line it outputs -- array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "BSmyth" [1]=> string(5) "James" [2]=> string(5) "Sally" }  so it seems to be looping.

And yes username is a little further to the left and it equals what is in user_subs.

Comment: Ok, added another option based on your details. One thing though, in the where clause of your update query, you are checking the username field against the post_author instead of the username. Is it how it is supposed to be?

Comment: hmm seems to have gone backwards, nothing is happening now and var_dump($user_subs) after implode returns NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144799/discussion-between-ayip-and-bradley-smith).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start over. Let's start here, in fact...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_subs;

CREATE TABLE user_subs
(user_id INT NOT NULL
, sub_id INT NOT NULL
, active TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
, PRIMARY KEY(user_id,sub_id)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES 
(1,'b.smyth634@gmail.com'),
(2,'james@gmail.com'),
(3,'f@gmail.com'),
(4,'sally@gmail.com'),
(5,'thomas@gmail.com');

INSERT INTO user_subs (user_id,sub_id) VALUES
(1,5),
(1,2),
(1,1),
(1,4),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(2,4);


SELECT * FROM users;
+---------+----------------------+
| user_id | email                |
+---------+----------------------+
|       1 | b.smyth634@gmail.com |
|       2 | james@gmail.com      |
|       3 | f@gmail.com          |
|       4 | sally@gmail.com      |
|       5 | thomas@gmail.com     |
+---------+----------------------+

SELECT * FROM user_subs;
+---------+--------+--------+
| user_id | sub_id | active |
+---------+--------+--------+
|       1 |      5 |      1 |
|       1 |      2 |      1 |
|       1 |      1 |      1 |
|       1 |      4 |      1 |
|       2 |      1 |      1 |
|       2 |      2 |      1 |
|       2 |      4 |      1 |
+---------+--------+--------+

SELECT u.*
     , GROUP_CONCAT(us.sub_id) subs 
  FROM users u 
  JOIN user_subs us 
    ON us.user_id = u.user_id 
 GROUP 
    BY u.user_id;
+---------+----------------------+---------+
| user_id | email                | subs    |
+---------+----------------------+---------+
|       1 | b.smyth634@gmail.com | 1,2,4,5 |
|       2 | james@gmail.com      | 1,2,4   |
+---------+----------------------+---------+
```

From here we have a choice. We can either `DELETE` subs we no longer wish to consider, or simply `UPDATE` them as 'inactive'.

Either way, we just need a `DELETE` or an `UPDATE`. So no `SELECT` needed. In fact a `SELECT` would, as I mentioned, be counterproductive - because a user may modify the data set in between the execution of the `SELECT` and the execution of the `UPDATE/DELETE`. This is known as a 'race condition'.